# Display list of files which are checked out in TFS before closing the visual studio solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I want to display a list of all the files which are checked out by the user in TFS. This is just incase user has checked out some files accidentally. Is there is a setting available in Visual Studio/TFS which can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Install [TFS Power Tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1), which provides additional menu options like by status, it can display all checked out.

> **Team Explorer Enhancements**
>
> This tool provides additional Visual Studio menu options and functions
>   to support **finding files under version control by status or wildcard,**
>   **opening a folder using File Explorer from the Source Control Explorer
>   context menu, and labeling files and folders in Source Control
>   Explorer**.  Clone builds definitions easily and copy work item paths.
>   Collaborate and share with your teammates within Visual Studio using
>   the Team Members page in the Team Explorer tool window. You can
>   communicate with your team through instant messaging, share queries
>   and components, create workspace templates, and track your sprint
>   progress.

[image]